# WIN32, Two windows using the same wndproc...why?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make two windows that use two different wndprocs.
I've created two separate wndprocs and two separate window classes which direct to their own wndproc callback.

But for some reason, both of the windows are using the same wndproc....
My second window should technically be using WndProcControl, however it's using WndProc like my first window is...

Why is it doing this?  Here is my code:

```
// Edit.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TaylorSoundEditor.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szControl[MAX_LOADSTRING]; //The title bar for the Control window
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
TCHAR szControlClass[MAX_LOADSTRING]; //the control window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
ATOM                MyRegisterControlClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProcControl(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_CONTROL_TITLE, szControl, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR, szControlClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    MyRegisterControlClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

ATOM MyRegisterControlClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX controlex;

    controlex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    controlex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    controlex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProcControl;
    controlex.cbClsExtra        = 0;
    controlex.cbWndExtra        = 0;
    controlex.hInstance     = hInstance;
    controlex.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR));
    controlex.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    controlex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    controlex.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR);
    controlex.lpszClassName = szControlClass;
    controlex.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(controlex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&controlex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd, controlWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   controlWnd = CreateWindow(szControlClass, szControl, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   ShowWindow(controlWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(controlWnd);
   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"TEXT", L"TESTTT", 0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcControl(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"TEXT2", L"TESTTT2", 0);
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("hello"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 200, 85, hWnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        //PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You load same string for both class names: with ID `IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR`... Your class names are the same.

Answer (score 14):

You attempt to register two window classes. But you have given them both the same class name. And so the second attempt fails. Then you create your two windows, passing the same window class name to both calls to `CreateWindow`.

Look at the calls you make to `LoadString`.

```
LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadString(hInstance, IDC_TAYLORSOUNDEDITOR, szControlClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
```

Clearly the result of this is that `szWindowClass` and `szControlClass` have the same value.

You would have discovered this yourself had you not ignored the return value of your calls to `RegisterClassEx`. The second call fails, for obvious reasons. Don't ignore return values!